# How to stop audit.json file occurring in node js-winston library

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, logging, winston

I have a node.js app. And I am logging everything using winston library. My logs are daily saved on my desktop in a file. When my logs are created, there is also an audit.json file that is created automatically with my logs. And this audit.json file is saved in my logs file as well. For every run, an audit.json file is created. I want to stop occurring this audit.json file. How can I do that? Any suggestion? When I click audit.json there is some parameters that are shown such as:

(I don't have internet on my work pc so I have to write on my phone sorry)

```
"keep" :
        "days" : false,
         "amount" :5
              }, 
"auditLog:" C:/Users/Desktop/LogFiles/.11cjeoepdwgeudp

"files":[

"date" :"1571727049689",
"name": "path"
"hash" :"054239856656...."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`audit.json` is an important file used by Winston to create a map of your log files. Without it, you won't be able to use the [daily-rotate](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston-daily-rotate-file) feature. In order to get rid of it and still use the mentioned submodule, you'd have to modify the code of [file-stream-rotator](https://github.com/rogerc/file-stream-rotator) - a module used by Winston. It's responsible for creating this file. You could, for example, implement a database store that would replace the json file.

The file is actually hidden on Linux systems and many users don't even know about it. Since you're using Windows, you could modify file-stream-rotator and add the `hidden` attribute every time the file is created. It would be much easier to achieve than moving the file map store to a database. [This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hidefile) module would be helpful if you decided to solve the problem in this way.

Comment: Hello again. I can't find file stream rotator file. How can I reach it?

Comment: It says the module doesn't exist (file-stream-rotator). How can I hide it

Comment: If you installed Winston with npm, you have to look inside the `node_modules` folder.

Comment: Thank you I found it! But my boss wants me to write a code that automatically deletes json files when it occurs in my logs file. I need to write something that finds all json files in my file and deletes them. Do you have an offer for me please?

Comment: should .audit.json be committed to source control?

Comment: @RamanSrinivasan Since you shouldn't commit any log files to source control, the `.audit.json` file should also be left out. It will be created automatically when you start the application.

Comment: @TomaszKasperczyk thanks for the confirmation. I wasnt sure if it was a log file or a config file.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is to add an entry to your `.gitignore` file (et al *****):

```
.*-audit.json
```

You asked how to prevent its creation, but I believe that ignoring the file is actually the correct solution.  These files are created at runtime by `winston-daily-rotate-file` and are used by that package to keep track of the log files that it rotates.

The next best solution would be to move the file to a location that works better for you.  You can control the location of this file by setting the [`auditFile` option](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston-daily-rotate-file#options) when you create the `DailyRotateFile` transport.

If you aren't convinced, and feel you really want to prevent the file from being created, the only simple solution is to remove your dependence upon `winston-daily-rotate-file`.  Otherwise, follow the advise given in [Tomasz' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58508077/361684), and modify dependency code, probably by forking one or more dependencies.

---

***** Eg, your package may also include other ignore files such as `.npmignore`.  It may be appropriate to include the same entry in any such files that exist in your package.